# Convert unix/linux filename character set to windows

Tags: linux, windows, unix, unicode, filenames

I used mkdir() to make some directories via PHP in Farsi and Arabic Languages.

I want to move folders into windows but have problem with folders names.

example: I wrote : "سلام"

but in windows show me unknown characters: "ط³غŒط³طھظ… ط¹ط§ظ…ظ„ ط¬ظ„ط¯ ط¯ظˆظ…"

seems it should be convert to other encoding except UTF-8

sorry if my English isn't very good.

Thank You.

Edit:
I used this Powershell code and worked for me:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
  $filename = Split-Path -Leaf $_
  $new = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($filename))
  if ($_.Name -ne $new) {
    Rename-Item $_ $new
  }
}
enter code here
```

but I want above code to correct all subfolders names too...

Comment: How, exactly, are you moving the folders between Linux and Windows?

Comment: yes. I used mkdir via PHP in Linux and now want to move to Windows...

Comment: Yes, but how? Flashdrive, harddisk or something like that? Which filesystem? ([FAT32, Ntfs, ...?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) Or copy over the network? Do you zip the files or just copy them?

Comment: It may also matter whether the Windows disk is FAT or NTFS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317748(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I believe Windows uses UTF-16 internally.

Comment: folders are in a Linux server and Windows is on my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> seems it should be convert to other encoding except UTF-8

Yes: when you use filename strings in the C standard library byte-based file interfaces (which is what PHP and most other cross-platform languages do), you get the Windows default ('ANSI') code page. This encoding is locale-dependent, and aggravatingly is never UTF-8.

In your case judging by the above filename, your default code page is 1256 Arabic. If you encode your filename as cp1256 then that should work:

```
$localfilename= iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1256', $filename);
```

However:

- this will mean you can use only Arabic (and ASCII) characters in filenames - any other Unicode characters will break;
- this will naturally fail if deployed on a different server whose default code page is not 1256. It's common for servers to be running in the US locale and pick up code page 1252 Western European instead.

Whilst you can in general change code pages, and UTF-8 is in principle available in Windows as code page 65001, there are a bunch of bugs with it that probably make that unusable for this purpose - UTF-8 is a second-class citizen under Windows. (In any case changing locale inside a web server thread is dodgy.)

The only way to get full Unicode filenames to work in Windows is to call the native Win32 API functions to access files (using UTF-16LE strings) instead of the C standard library functions. This is what PowerShell/.NET does - as it's Windows-specific software it can afford to go straight to the Win32 functions. Python also has support for Unicode filenames that go to Win32 instead of C.

However PHP does not have this capability at present. You could do it manually by using [w32api_invoke_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.w32api-invoke-function.php) to call the Win32 API [CreateDirectoryW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly, but it'd be really inconvenient.

This is one reason why it's best to avoid using arbitrary input as filenames if at all possible!

Comment: the first solution was very good.

I used that code in a while to rename subdirectories...

however for a folder returns error:

Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string.
tnx :)

Comment: @Ramin: Yes, that is what will happen when any character is encountered that is not present in Arabic code page 1256. If you use the target encoding `windows-1256//IGNORE` then it will silently throw away those characters instead of raising an error, but obviously this means losing data.

Comment: Finaly I use a code to replace and prevent losing some data (for Persian/Farsi language):

$localfilename = str_ireplace('ی','ي',$localfilename);
then we can rename folder :)

Comment: Is that the right way around? `ي` (U+064A, Arabic Yeh) is present in cp1256 whereas `ی` (U+06CC, Farsi Yeh) isn't. There are quite a few other Arabic characters that aren't in 1256 too, so if you have to do it again with new data this might not suffice...

Comment: Yes, I know that some characters in Farsi such as ('گ', 'ژ', 'پ') are not in Arabic. But this method worked for me very well without losing any data !

Comment: Yes, I know that some characters in